# How to pass async in @Input Angular?

Tags: angular

I have input property `[visitors]`:

```
<app-visitor-component [visitors]="visitors"></app-visitor-component>
```

How replace `[visitors]="visitors"` on async like:

```
[visitors]="service.currentUser | async"
```

Comment: Why you just don't send it as Observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your service is an Observable you need to use an Elvis operator:

```
[visitors]="(service | async)?.currentUser"
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to make filter based this notation? I mean when I typing text in input I need to filter (service.currentUser| async)

Comment: The first solution is a create method in a component and use a pipe on an observable with a map operator, second is a create filter pipe which maps your property as in the first solution. It's more convenient and friendly for change detection (search in the Google: pure pipes).

Answer (score 1):

You could send it as Observable , if not use async as follows

```
<app-child [visitors]="(service.currentUser| async)">
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to make filter based this notation? I mean when I typing text in input I need to  filter (service.currentUser| async)

Comment: @OPV you need to pass the observable,  then in the child component you need to subcribe to it and filter the values

Answer (score 1):

Make the variable you are passing an `Observable` or `Subject<T>` or `BehaviourSubject<T>`

eg.

```
// some service
public currentUser: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
```

then use like

```
[visitors]="service.currentUser | async"
```